# E:The key specification is incomplete. Generic specification is only completed

Tags: abap

When clicking on Check (CTRL + F2) I get the error:

E:The key specification is incomplete. Generic specification is only completed

Unfortunately there I do not see an indicator which line is wrong. Thx SAP :/

Therefore here the relevant code:

```
      SELECT /bic/customer FROM /bic/pcustomer INTO TABLE i_pcustomer
        WHERE objvers = c_a.
  SELECT /bic/material /bic/sdcsnum FROM /bic/pmaterial INTO TABLE i_pmaterial_s
        WHERE objvers = c_a.

  SORT i_pmaterial_s BY /bic/material.
  i_pmaterial = i_pmaterial_s.
  DELETE i_pmaterial_s WHERE /bic/sdcsnum IS INITIAL.

*write to log in infopackage - check double entries material
  SORT i_pmaterial_s BY /bic/sdcsnum.

  LOOP AT i_pmaterial_s INTO i_pmaterial_s_line.
    IF sy-tabix = 1.
      CLEAR flg_dup.
    ELSE.
      IF i_pmaterial_dcs_line-/bic/sdcsnum = i_pmaterial_s_line-/bic/sdcsnum.
        "CLEAR p_t_errorlog.
        l_cnt = l_cnt + 1.
        p_t_errorlog_line-msgid = 'VRS'.
        p_t_errorlog_line-msgty = 'I'.
        p_t_errorlog_line-msgno = 0.
        p_t_errorlog_line-msgv1 = 'Duplic. rec:'.
        p_t_errorlog_line-msgv2 = '/BIC/PMATERIAL DCS'.
        p_t_errorlog_line-msgv3 = i_pmaterial_dcs_line-/bic/sdcsnum.
        p_t_errorlog_line-msgv4 = i_pmaterial_dcs_line-/bic/material.
        insert p_t_errorlog_line into table p_t_errorlog.
        flg_dup = 'X'.
      ELSE.
        IF flg_dup IS INITIAL.
          INSERT i_pmaterial_dcs_line into i_pmaterial_dcs.
        ELSE.
          "CLEAR p_t_errorlog.
          l_cnt = l_cnt + 1.
          p_t_errorlog_line-msgid = 'VRS'.
          p_t_errorlog_line-msgty = 'I'.
          p_t_errorlog_line-msgno = 0.
          p_t_errorlog_line-msgv1 = 'Duplic. rec:'.
          p_t_errorlog_line-msgv2 = '/BIC/PMATERIAL DCS'.
          p_t_errorlog_line-msgv3 = i_pmaterial_dcs_line-/bic/sdcsnum.
          p_t_errorlog_line-msgv4 = i_pmaterial_dcs_line-/bic/material.
          insert p_t_errorlog_line into table p_t_errorlog.
          CLEAR flg_dup.
        ENDIF.
      ENDIF.
    ENDIF.
    i_pmaterial_dcs_line = i_pmaterial_s_line.
  ENDLOOP.
```

Comment: The code is incomplete - it does not include the `DATA` statements of the relevant variables.

Answer (score -1):

The code which triggered the error message was:

```
data: p_t_errorlog TYPE SORTED TABLE OF rsmonitor
```

changing the code to

```
data: p_t_errorlog TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF rsmonitor
```

fixed the issue.

Comment: Depending on the task at hand, this might make the situation worse. You can't simply change any sorted table to a standard table and expect the program to continue to work as before.

Comment: If this is a solution and nothing was broken with this edit then mark this as an answer.